# ultimo theme brand slider dont work

Tags: magento, slider

I have Magento with Ultimo Theme
I have Set Up the Brand Slider on Home Page
It shows 4 Brands with images. I have 6 Brands. Only the first 4 ore shown
and it doesnt slider to the other

Have anyone an idea?

Here is my code:

```
{{block type=”brands/brands” template=”infortis/brands/brand_slider.phtml” breakpoints=”[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 2], [768, 3], [960, 4], [1280, 5]” move=”1″ pagination=”1″ block_name=”Our Brands”}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must add "brands/brands" to System-Permissions-Blocks

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.

```
<div class="col-md-12" class="our_brands_block" style="background-color: #f0f2fb;>
{{block class="Infortis\Brands\Block\Brands" template="brand_slider.phtml" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 2], [768, 5], [960, 6], [1280, 6]" move=1 loop=1 timeout=1000 speed=500 pagination=1}}
</div>
```

Add the content above as a CMS block.
Configure a widget as.
Page: CMS Pages (All)
Container: Postscript, Full Width

This adds it full width just above the footer area.

But lazy load does not appear to work and animation is not working.

Magento 2.3.0